# I can't see my ISO image on virtual box

Tags: windows

I am trying to install windows to my virtual box but I can't see CD/DVD in storage instead I see ( Choose virtual optical disk file )  anybody now what's going on
Last time it was working ok but now it is not working.

Comment: Can you take some screenshots of your machine settings and the error you're getting?

Comment: Did you just try to select the file?

Comment: CD/DVD option is disappeared from virtual box, i do have the screenshot but here's no attached option to attach the screenshot .